# Can an RDP client use .NET on the RDP host?

Tags: .net, windows, rdp, terminal-services, terminal-server

I'm pretty sure I know the answer to this but I'd like to confirm with the experts.

I have a client who is utilizing .NET 4.6.2...When they connect to a Terminal Server, can the client's version of .NET be used on that TS session? So, ultimately the TS would use the same .NET as the client that's connecting to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you're using RDP, you're using resources on the host. That's kind of the whole point.